# How to hide and open navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to hide and open the navigation i'v created with the "+" and "-" buttons
- when user will click on the '+' button the navigation will start open one by one.
(notice: the links are on display: none; right now)

fiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/RKhRy/5/

The css:

```
.nav {
    height: 600px;
    width: 150px;
       display: none;
}

.nav li {
    width: 150px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #232323;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#close {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #737373;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 150px;
    position: absolute;
     line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
 display: none;
}

#open {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #232323;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
     line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
```

Comment: can't able to understand even I had read this twice. Provide some more details.

Comment: Please form a question with what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I'V put another explaination under the '-' there

Comment: You probably want to read up on jQuery `slideToggle()` to do this.

Comment: @FillipPeyton Here i put an edit

Comment: have you attempted to tackle this problem at all by yourself?

Comment: @seanxe i don't have a starting point

Comment: @anonblack start here http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @leaksterrr update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this jQuery code:

```
$("#open").click(function(){
    $(".nav, #close").show();
    $(".nav li").each(function (i) {
        $(this).delay(300*i).animate({width:150},300); 
    });
    $("#open").hide();
});

$("#close").click(function(){
    $("#close").hide();
    $($(".nav li").get().reverse()).each(function (i) {
        $(this).delay(300*i).animate({width:0},300); 
    });
    $("#open").show();
});
```

The result can be seen in this [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6xVNz/)

Comment: This is great can it slide horizontelly?

Comment: Sure, just add `float:left;` to _.nav li_ and change the width of _.nav_ to make all links fit.

Comment: Also you need to change the css of _#close_ and _#open_ so that they won't be in the way, maybe add `float:left;` to them too.

Comment: Good job on the jQuery animation! :)

Comment: @DanielLisik FIRST-THANKS SO MUCH FOR YOUR EFFEROT second i want it will stay as it was just the !sliding! will be horizontally

Comment: @DanielLisik the sliding of each catagory

Comment: @alonblack, what didn't satisfy you with my solution?

Comment: @DanielLisik so sorry i thought i gave u the right answer, one last thing can i make the links start sliding not just when the prev end ?

Comment: @DanielLisik In parallel and not just when the prev ending for better animation (smoother)

Comment: That won't be too easy. If you change the animation duration to a small value that delay shouldn't be noticed, but I will try to fix that.

Comment: It turns out that running two JavaScript functions in exact parallell isn't possible. You can read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318615/how-to-activate-two-javascript-functions-in-parallel With that said, I think your best bet is to make the animation rather quick, which will make the delay practically unnoticable.

Comment: @alonblack, the closest I came to stopping the animation to complete before sliding back was by adding `$(".nav li").stop(true, false);` in the beginning of each function. Hope it helps!

Comment: @DanielLisik can you plz take a look at this link http://tekroc.com/ in the left click it this is what i'm trying to do

Comment: You can create the same effect as on the site by changing your CSS and jQuery a little bit. With the jQuery foundation I provided I believe you could manage this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why i've coded for you but the building blocks of what you're after are here in an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RKhRy/12/

Use jQuery's `slideToggle();`

Comment: this is great thanks so much... can i make it slide horizontally each time?each catagory i want to slide horizontally

Comment: In order to this you need to animate the width property using jquery or css3. Animate the width from 0 to 100%. If however you're trying to achieve a 'slide out' type navigation whereby the whole document slides to the right while the nav pushes in from the left then you want to animate the left properly.

Answer (score 2):

I've edited your example to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/g8AF6/3/

new CSS:

```
body {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-weight: bold;
    position:relative;
}
.nav {
    height: 600px;
    width: 150px;
    display: none;
}
#open:focus{
    visibility:hidden;
}
#open:focus + #close + .nav{
    display:block;
}
#open:focus + #close {
    display:block;
}
.nav li {
    width: 150px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #232323;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#close {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #737373;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

#open {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #232323;
    color: #fff;
     line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

now just add transitions for collapse/expand animation

regards

Answer (score 2):

Basic working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/phdphil/YJ8gf/#base

Essentially this bit of code, plus an `id=nav` in the right tag:

```
function setNavVisible(visible) {
    var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    var close = document.getElementById('close');
    var open = document.getElementById('open');
    if(visible) {
        nav.style.display = "block";
        close.style.display = "block";
        open.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        nav.style.display = "none";
        close.style.display = "none";
        open.style.display = "block";
    }
}   


document.getElementById('open').onclick = function() {
    setNavVisible(true);    
}

document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
    setNavVisible(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've cloned and editted your fiddle. Your html is wrong. You can't have li inside of divs. Thinking of that, your open and close divs can be refactored to something more semanthic. Like this:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle Menu</a> 
<ul class="nav">
    <li>START HERE</li> 
    <li>ABOUT</li>  
    <li>PORTFOLIO</li>  
    <li>BRANDS</li>  
    <li>SERVICES</li>  
    <li>CONTACT</li>  
</ul>
```

I've also added pseudo-elements in css instead of having two elements to only one function.

Check the result here:
http://jsfiddle.net/H7ms7/

Comment: can each catagory slide horizontally

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind keydown event with CSS in my mind.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == *NUMBER) { 
}
)};
```

*The number should be the one that + or - trigger with.

The next thing is with the css, I would just bind `$("#element").css('display','block');` With the triggers you want.

If you want them one by one like you said, I'm not absulotly sure but I know it might have to do with **CSS3 transition**. Check it out, dont want to mislead you.

Goodluck