# Recurring AJAX calls with different URLs

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, sapui5, handsontable

I am trying to fetch data in batches. Therefore I need to place AJAX calls in recurrence by modifying the URL. However I am unsuccessful, since every time I get the same data. I tried something mentioned here:

[Can we make parallel Service calls using Spring framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154084/can-we-make-parallel-service-calls-using-spring-framework)

but with no luck.

My code goes as follows. Please let me know if I have gone wrong somewhere in the code or if I should try out a different approach.

```
var HOT;
var itemData = []; 
var itemObj;
var pgNum = 1;
var javaurl = "http://172.23.37.22/AVR/Rest/retrieveItems/1";
RetrieveInfo: function(javaurl) {
        var that = this;
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.model.odata.datajs");
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            contentType : 'application/json',
            dataType : 'json',
            crossDomain : true,
            url : javaurl,
            success : function(data, status, request) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.itemdataGen.length; i++) {
                    var dataArray = [];
                    dataArray[0] = data.itemdataGen[i].mscItemNum;
                    dataArray[1] = data.itemdataGen[i].attributeName;
                    dataArray[2] = data.itemdataGen[i].curValue;
                    dataArray[3] = data.itemdataGen[i].newValue;

                    itemData[i] = dataArray
                }
                itemObj = data.endOfData;
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("No success");
            },
            complete: function() {
                HOT.loadData(itemData);
            }
        }); 
        if(itemObj=="false"){
             pgNum++;
             javaurl = "http://172.23.37.22/AVR/Rest/retrieveItems/"+pgNum;
             that.RetrieveInfo(javaurl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the parameters that are sent to the server and whether the page number is always 1?

Comment: try moving the `if(itemObj=="false")`-block into your success-function

Comment: Thanks @herrlock. It worked after moving the block into success function.